# Compute: $ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\ln(px^2+qx+t)}{x^2+mx+n} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I'd like to know if there are some nice ways to solve this type of integral defined as:

$$ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\ln(px^2+qx+t)}{x^2+mx+n} \ dx$$

A few days ago I saw such an integral and it seemed pretty tricky since it's rather hard
to figure out where to start from.

Comment: is there any relation between $p,q$ and $m$

Comment: @avatar: I didn't take into account any relation of this kind.

Comment: As non-mathematicians often do, this posting uses "solve" as a catch-all verb.  "Evaluate" would be appropriate.  One _solves_ problems; one _solves_ equations; one _evaluates_ expressions.

Comment: FWIW: if you depress the quadratic within the logarithm and then perform partial fraction decomposition, you should end up with integrals of the form $$\int\frac{\log(au^2+c)}{u+f}\mathrm du$$ whose integration will involve the dilogarithm.

Comment: @ J. M.: this way it looks much better.

Comment: @Chris'sister : I frequently see the word "solve" mis-used in just that way not only in this forum, but in homework handed in by students, and elsewhere.  I've never seen it in a paper written by a mathematician.

Comment: If $p,q=0$ then well-known partial fraction gives the answer.  If $p=0$, $q\neq 0$ then the result contains the polylogarithm function, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate&a=*C.integrate-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=ln%28q*x%2Bt%29%2F%28x^2%2Bm*x%2Bn%29&x=10&y=4&f=Integral.integrand_ln%28q*x%2Bt%29%2F%28x^2%2Bm*x%2Bn%29&f3=x&f=Integral.variable_x&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Integral.rangestart-.*Integral.rangeend---.**Integral.variable---

Comment: If $p\neq 0$ then the result also contains the polylogarythm function, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate&a=*C.integrate-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=ln%28p*x^2%2Bq*x%2Bt%29%2F%28x^2%2Bm*x%2Bn%29&x=7&y=3&f=Integral.integrand_ln%28p*x^2%2Bq*x%2Bt%29%2F%28x^2%2Bm*x%2Bn%29&f3=x&f=Integral.variable_x&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Integral.rangestart-.*Integral.rangeend---.**Integral.variable---          Although some discussion is needed because the square root of some quantities.

Comment: @Chris'sister could you share us where saw such an integral and what does it mean "pretty tricky"? If I know well you have the possibility to ask and answer (Q&A) an interesting question if you think it would be useful for the community.

Comment: @vesszabo: I saw it during summer classes. Our teacher said this kind of problem is very nice and it's worth to try it.

Comment: Really, your teacher expects you to know dilogarithms?

Answer (score 3):

This might be helpful:

Let $$I(p)= \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\ln(px^2+qx+t)}{x^2+mx+n} \ dx$$

Now take derivative both sides w.r.t. $p$ gives $$I'(p)=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\partial(\frac{\ln(px^2+qx+t)}{x^2+mx+n})}{\partial p} \ dx$$ $$=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+mx+n)(px^2+qx+t)}dx$$ 
which we can integrate using some standard substitutions . Then integrate $I'(p)$ w.r.t. $p$ to get $I(p)$.

Comment: This doesn't solves anything. After evaluating $I'(p)$ you get such a weird expressions that subsequent integration with respect to $p$ is hopeless. You can check it using WA.

Comment: @ Norbert: I've just checked it and you're right.

Comment: Clearly, the people who upvoted didn't try to follow through with this approach. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This may also help, though it does not evaluate this integral completely.

$$
\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\log(px^2+qx+t)}{x^2+mx+n} \, dx=
\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\log(p(|x-x_1|)(|x-x_2|)}{x^2+mx+n} \, dx=
$$
where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of $px^2+qx+t$.

$$
\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\log(p)+\log|x-x_1| + \log |x-x_2|}{x^2+mx+n} \, dx=
\log(p) \int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{x^2+mx+n}\, dx+\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\log|x-x_1|}{x^2+mx+n}\, dx+\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\log |x-x_2|}{x^2+mx+n}\, dx
$$

Comment: I think you should write $|x-x_1|$ , $|x-x_2|$ instead of $x-x_1$, $x-x_2$. Also you approach doesn't work when this roots doesn't exist